# Menu toggle add spacing (margin) if clicked

Tags: jquery, css, margin, spacing

Any idea why my code won't work as wanted? If I click it the first two times when the mobile navi is toggled it works fine but the third time it doesn't add the margin as I want.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $("#site-navigation.main-navigation").click(function(){
    $("#page").css("margin-top", "285px");
  });

  $("#site-navigation.main-navigation.toggled").click(function(){
    $("#page").css("margin-top", "0px");
  });
});
```

Comment: 1) You need to include the HTML for anyone to be able to debug. 2) Your code snippet is not properly formatted for StackOverflow- you need to separately add the Javascript and HTML into different portions of the snippet editor so that they can be run automatically.

Comment: Also, you are not closing the first click function properly...

Comment: I feel like this logic as is, is going to have an issue because it is defining bindings on elements based upon their initial state upon page load.  Adding/removing the `toggled` class from the main-navigation element will not cause it to start using the other binding.  It will only ever use the bindings that are placed on it.  This short coming of direct bindings can be over come by using a delegate binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two events are firing at the same time when `#site-navigation.main-navigation` has the ".toggle" class. That's not what you intended. This code will do what you want.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#site-navigation.main-navigation").click(function(){
        if ( $(this).hasClass('toggled') ) {
            $("#page").css("margin-top", "0px");
        } else {
            $("#page").css("margin-top", "285px");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: In this case it doesn't matter, order of event listeners makes it work as it should, there must be some other issue, maybe with html we could tell more

Answer (score 0):

Toggle a CSS class.

```js
document.getElementById("foo").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  this.classList.toggle("bump-it");
});
```

```css
.bump-it{
  margin-left:24px;
}
```

```html
<button id="foo">
click me
</button>
```